# Cannot invoke method channel in another activity

Tags: android, flutter

In MainActivity.kt, I invoke a method call "goToSecondActivity" to go to second activity. I would like to invoke method channel on the SecondActivity too but it doesn't work. The MethodCallHandler doesn't even run.

I got the `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method updatePosition on channel com.example.ble_poc/map_channel)` but I have just implemented it and channel name is the same.

Can anyone tell me what should I do? I am new to Android Native.

`MainActivtiy.kt`:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.ble_poc/channel"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegister.registerGeneratedPlugins(FlutterEngine(this@MainActivity))
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine?.dartExecutor!!, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if(call.method.equals("goToSecondActivity")){
                goToSecondActivity()
            } else {
                print("Result not implemented in MainActivity")
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun goToSecondActivity() {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

`SecondActivity.kt`:

```
class SecondActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.ble_poc/map_channel"

    private lateinit var mapView: MPIMapView
    private val venueDataString: String by lazy { readFileContentFromAssets("mappedin-demo-mall.json") }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegister.registerGeneratedPlugins(FlutterEngine(this@SecondActivity))
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine?.dartExecutor!!.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if(call.method.equals("updatePosition")){
                println("Update position call is triggered")
                val lat = call.argument<Double>("lat")
                val long = call.argument<Double>("long")
                val accuracy = call.argument<Double>("accuracy") ?: 7.170562529369844
                val floorLevel = call.argument<Int>("floor") ?: 0
                updatePosition(lat!!, long!!, accuracy, floorLevel)
            } else {
                print("Result not implemented in SecondActivity")
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
...
```

`main.dart`

```
static const CHANNEL = "com.example.ble_poc/channel";
static const MAP_CHANNEL = "com.example.ble_poc/map_channel";
static const platform = MethodChannel(CHANNEL);
static const map_platform = MethodChannel(MAP_CHANNEL);

void openMap() async {
  try {
    platform.invokeMethod('goToSecondActivity');
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      map_platform.invokeMethod(
        "updatePosition",
        {
          "lat": 43.52023014,
          "long": -80.5352595,
        },
      );
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Please check the CHANNEL you have used for second activity. Is it the same channel name when you are sending the data again which needs to be captured in second activity? If possible please share the code of sending data from flutter side so we can share exact solution.

Comment: @ABV I have shared the main.dart code. I am sure the channel name are the same